# How to merge two enums in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, types, enums, merge, typescript2.0

Suppose I have two enums as described below in Typescript, then How do I merge them

```
enum Mammals {
    Humans,
    Bats,
    Dolphins
}

enum Reptiles {
    Snakes,
    Alligators,
    Lizards
}

export default Mammals & Reptiles // For Illustration purpose, Consider both the Enums have been merged.
```

Now, when I `import` the `exported value` in another file, I should be able to access values from both the enums.

```
import animalTypes from "./animalTypes"

animalTypes.Humans //valid

animalTypes.Snakes // valid
```

How can I achieve such functionality in TypeScript?

Answer (score 214):

## Problems with the merge:

- same values => values are overwritten
- same keys => keys are overwritten
- ❌ Enums with same values (=> values are overwritten)

```
enum AA1 {
  aKey, // = 0
  bKey // = 1
}
enum BB1 {
  cKey, // = 0
  dKey // = 1
}
```

- ❌ Enums with the same keys (=> keys are overwritten)

```
enum AA2 {
  aKey = 1
}
enum BB2 {
  aKey = 2
}
```

- ✅ Good

```
enum AA3 {
  aKey, // = 0
  bKey // = 1
}
enum BB3 {
  cKey = 2,
  dKey // = 3
}
```

- ✅ Also Good

```
enum AA4 {
  aKey = 'Hello',
  bKey = 0,
  cKey // = 1
}
enum BB4 {
  dKey = 2,
  eKey = 'Hello',
  fKey = 'World'
}
```

Note:
`aKey = 'Hello'` and `eKey = 'Hello'` work because the enum with a string value doesn't has this value as key

```
// For aKey = 'Hello', key is working
type aa4aKey = AA4.aKey; // = AA4.aKey
// value is not.
type aa4aValue = AA4.Hello; // ❌ Namespace 'AA4' has no exported member 'Hello'
type aa4aValue2 = AA4['Hello']; // ❌ Property 'Hello' does not exist on type 'AA4'

console.log(AA4); // { 0: 'bKey', 1: 'cKey', aKey: 'Hello', bKey: 0, cKey: 1 }
console.log(BB4); // { 2: 'dKey', dKey: 2, eKey: 'Hello', fKey: 'World' }
```

## The merge

- ❌ using union types

```
type AABB1 = AA4 | BB4; // = AA4 | BB4
type AABB1key = AABB1['aKey']; // = never
type AABB1key2 = AABB1.aKey; // ❌ 'AABB1' only refers to a type, but is being used as a namespace here. ts(2702)
```

- ❌ using intersection types

```
type AABB1 = AA4 & BB4; // = never
type AABB1key = AABB1['aKey']; // = never
```

- ✅ using intersection types with typeof

```
type AABB2 = (typeof AA4) & (typeof BB4); // = typeof AA4 & typeof BB4
type AABB2key = AABB2['aKey']; // = AA4.aKey
```

- ✅ using js copy

```
const aabb1 = { ...AA4, ...BB4 };
const aabb2 = Object.assign({}, AA4, BB4); // also work
// aabb1 = {
// 0: 'bKey',
// 1: 'cKey',
// 2: 'dKey',
// aKey: 'Hello',
// bKey: 0,
// cKey: 1,
// dKey: 2,
// eKey: 'Hello',
// fKey: 'World' }
```

- ✅ using typeof with a js copy

```
const aabb = { ...AA4, ...BB4 };
type TypeofAABB = typeof aabb;
// type TypeofAABB = {
// [x: number]: string;
// dKey: BB4.dKey;
// eKey: BB4.eKey;
// fKey: BB4.fKey;
// aKey: AA4.aKey;
// bKey: AA4.bKey;
// cKey: AA4.cKey;
// };
```

Tip: you can use the same name for a type and a value

```
const merged = { ...AA4, ...BB4 };
type merged = typeof merged;

const aValue = merged.aKey;
type aType = merged['aKey'];
```

## Your case

If you want to merge your 2 enums you have ~3 choices:

### 1. Using string enums

```
enum Mammals {
  Humans = 'Humans',
  Bats = 'Bats',
  Dolphins = 'Dolphins'
}

enum Reptiles {
  Snakes = 'Snakes',
  Alligators = 'Alligators',
  Lizards = 'Lizards'
}

export const Animals = { ...Mammals, ...Reptiles };
export type Animals = typeof Animals;
```

### 2. Using unique numbers

```
enum Mammals {
  Humans = 0,
  Bats,
  Dolphins
}

enum Reptiles {
  Snakes = 2,
  Alligators,
  Lizards
}

export const Animals = { ...Mammals, ...Reptiles };
export type Animals = typeof Animals;
```

### 3. Using nested enums

```
enum Mammals {
  Humans,
  Bats,
  Dolphins
}

enum Reptiles {
  Snakes,
  Alligators,
  Lizards
}

export const Animals = { Mammals, Reptiles };
export type Animals = typeof Animals;

const bats = Animals.Mammals.Bats; // = 1
const alligators = Animals.Reptiles.Alligators; // = 1
```

Note: you can also merge the nested enums with the following code. Take care to NOT have duplicated values if you do that!

```
type Animal = {
  [K in keyof Animals]: {
    [K2 in keyof Animals[K]]: Animals[K][K2]
  }[keyof Animals[K]]
}[keyof Animals];

const animal: Animal = 0 as any;

switch (animal) {
  case Animals.Mammals.Bats:
  case Animals.Mammals.Dolphins:
  case Animals.Mammals.Humans:
  case Animals.Reptiles.Alligators:
  case Animals.Reptiles.Lizards:
  case Animals.Reptiles.Snakes:
    break;
  default: {
    const invalid: never = animal; // no error
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't use the nested enum with a switch

Comment: @lolelo

You can do it in a little hackish way with typescript.
Here is a sample (also in edited answer):http://pastiebin.com/5d681d2cde9cc

Comment: How did you put those "RED" cross and "GREEN" ticks ? :D

Comment: @ShashankVivek basically copy/pasting emojis (symbols section). They are a great ressource for written explanations :)

Comment: for example 1 and 2, instead of

`export type Animals = typeof Animals;`

you should be doing

`export type Animals = Mammals | Reptiles`;

so that mammal is assignable to animal

Comment: Thanks Théry Fouchter for the wonderful answer and @maboesanman for the great addition. I was stuck on this for quite a while.

Comment: Thorough, but as @maboesanman pointed out, you got the type merge wrong. Then you can do `const a: Animals = Animals.Bats` like a normal `enum`.

Comment: It appears the intersection with `typeof` doesn't work for TS 4.8: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.2&ssl=11&ssc=1&pln=11&pc=44#code/KYOwrgtgBAKsDOAXAjFA3gKClAhlAvFAEQ5EA0WUARgcVeRgL4YaiSwKIBM6lehJBthoD6FZhkQBPAA7AoAMQD2S2gAppcpQDMOSZAEooAMigbZwHXu4GA3EA. The last version it worked with was 3.8.3: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.8.3#code/KYOwrgtgBAKsDOAXAjFA3gKClAhlAvFAEQ5EA0WUARgcVeRgL4YaiSwKIBM6lehJBthoD6FZhkQBPAA7AoAMQD2S2gAppcpQDMOSZAEooAMigbZwHXu4GA3EA

Comment: @maboesanman - the union type does allow for assignment to the `:Animal` type (which is probably the bigger use case), however it prevents you from accessing types using `:Animals["Snakes"]`. I created a playground to showcase the pros and cons of the different examples provide by you and this answer: https://tsplay.dev/mAQOBm

Answer (score 88):

If you want something behaving like an enum from the way you consume it, you could still use merged object in javascript.

```
enum Mammals {
    Humans = 'Humans',
    Bats = 'Bats',
    Dolphins = 'Dolphins',
}

enum Reptiles {
  Snakes = 'Snakes',
  Alligators = 'Alligators',
  Lizards = 'Lizards',
}

const Animals = {
   ...Mammals,
   ...Reptiles,
}

type Animals = Mammals | Reptiles
```

Then you could use Animals.Snakes or Animals.Dolphins and both should be properly typed and work as an enum

Comment: haven't really thought this angle... will try it.

Comment: add `type Animals = Mammals | Reptiles;` from @Porkishka answer and it works and passes type checks

Comment: how would I go about exporting `Animals` now?

Comment: if you export both the variable and the type you should not have any issues

Comment: Thanks for this answer - it's short and to the point, and it works...mostly. It suffers from not being able to access the types via `const foo: Animals["Snakes"]`. That can be fixed if you change the last line to `type Animals = typeof Animals;`

Comment: My previous comment is correct, but now that causes other problems such that you can't do what you normally want to do such as `const foo: Animals = Animals.Snakes`, which is sad. Apparently this behavior has changed over the years. You currently need to define two separate types if you want assign a value like you normally would AND access the type via `Animals["Snakes"]`. This is unfortunate.

Answer (score 23):

### Enums, interfaces and types - a working solution for merging enums

What's confusing here is types vs. values.

- If you define a **value** (`let`, `const` etc.) it will have a value plus some computed but not separately named type.
- If you define a **`type`** or `interface`, it will create a named type but that will not be outputted or considered in the final JS in any way. It only helps when writing your app.
- If you create an [**`enum`**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) in Typescript, it creates a static type name that you can use *plus* a real object outputted to JS that you can use.

From the TS handbook:

> Using an enum is simple: just access any member as a property off of the enum itself, and declare types using the name of the enum.

So, if you `Object.assign()` two enums, it will create a new, merged *value* (object), but not a new named type.

Since it's not an `enum` anymore, you lose the advantage of having a value and a named type, but you can still create a separate type name as a workaround.

Fortunately, you can have the same name for the value and the type, and TS will import both if you export them.

```
// This creates a merged enum, but not a type
const Animals = Object.assign({}, Mammals, Reptiles);

// Workaround: create a named type (typeof Animals won't work here!)
type Animals = Mammals | Reptiles;
```

[TS playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=enum%20Mammals%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Humans%20%3D%20%22humans%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Bats%20%3D%20%22bats%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Dolphins%20%3D%20%22dolphins%22%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aenum%20Reptiles%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Snakes%20%3D%20%22snakes%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Alligators%20%3D%20%22alligators%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Lizards%20%3D%20%22lizards%22%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20This%20creates%20a%20merged%20enum%2C%20but%20not%20a%20type%0D%0Aconst%20Animals%20%3D%20Object.assign(%7B%7D%2C%20Mammals%2C%20Reptiles)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(JSON.stringify(Animals))%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%7B%22Humans%22%3A%22humans%22%2C%22Bats%22%3A%22bats%22%2C...%2C%22Lizards%22%3A%22lizards%22%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Workaround%3A%20create%20a%20named%20type%20(typeof%20Animals%20won%27t%20work%20here!)%0D%0Atype%20AnimalsT%20%3D%20Mammals%20%7C%20Reptiles%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20This%20works%20-%20accessing%20value%0D%0AAnimals.Bats%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20But%20this%20doesn%27t%20-%20accessing%20type%0D%0Ainterface%20AnimalInt%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Mammals%3A%20value%20AND%20type%0D%0A%20%20%20%20mammal%3F%3A%20Mammals%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Animals%3A%20only%20value%2C%20no%20named%20type%0D%0A%20%20%20%20anyAnimal%3F%3A%20Animals%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20betterAnimal%3F%3A%20AnimalsT%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20animal%3A%20AnimalInt%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20betterAnimal%3A%20Animals.Bats%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: I appreciate about the workaround. typeof didn't work for me

Answer (score 7):

A TypeScript enum not only contains the keys you define but also the numerical inverse, so for example:

```
Mammals.Humans === 0 && Mammals[0] === 'Humans'
```

Now, if you try to merge them -- for example with `Object#assign` -- you'd end up with two keys having the same numerical value:

```
const AnimalTypes = Object.assign({}, Mammals, Reptiles);
console.log(AnimalTypes.Humans === AnimalTypes.Snakes) // true
```

And I suppose that's not what you want.

One way to prevent this, is to manually assign the values to the enum and make sure that they are different:

```
enum Mammals {
    Humans = 0,
    Bats = 1,
    Dolphins = 2
}

enum Reptiles {
    Snakes = 3,
    Alligators = 4,
    Lizards = 5
}
```

or less explicit but otherwise equivalent:

```
enum Mammals {
    Humans,
    Bats,
    Dolphins
}

enum Reptiles {
    Snakes = 3,
    Alligators,
    Lizards
}
```

Anyway, as long as you make sure that the enums you merge have different key/value sets you can merge them with `Object#assign`.

**[Playground Demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=enum%20Mammals%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Humans%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Bats%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Dolphins%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aenum%20Reptiles%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Snakes%20%3D%203%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Alligators%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Lizards%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20AnimalTypes%20%3D%20Object.assign(%7B%7D%2C%20Mammals%2C%20Reptiles)%3B)**

Comment: The merging seems to works, But I cannot use that in an interface. Playground Demo below. @Tao

Comment: [TS Playground Demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=enum%20Mammals%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Humans%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Bats%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Dolphins%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aenum%20Reptiles%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Snakes%20%3D%203%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Alligators%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Lizards%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20AnimalTypes%20%3D%20Object.assign(%7B%7D%2C%20Mammals%2C%20Reptiles)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Creature%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20AnimalTypes.Bats%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20AnotherCreature%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20Mammals.Humans%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: I guess the problem is that the merged object isn't an enum anymore for TypeScript although it behaves the same. As a workaraound you can write `typeof AnimalTypes.Bats` which will resolve to `Mammals.Bats`. Maybe someone else knows a better way.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use string ids for enum values and right export types:

```
enum Mammals {
  Humans = 'humans',
  Bats = 'bats',
  Dolphins = 'dolphins',
}

enum Reptiles {
  Snakes = 'snakes',
  Alligators = 'alligators',
  Lizards = 'lizards',
}

export const Animals = { ...Mammals, ...Reptiles };
type TAnimalsKeys = keyof typeof Animals;
export type TAnimal = typeof Animals[TAnimalsKeys];
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd say the proper way to do it would be defining a new type:

```
enum Mammals {
    Humans = 'Humans',
    Bats = 'Bats',
    Dolphins = 'Dolphins',
}

enum Reptiles {
  Snakes = 'Snakes',
  Alligators = 'Alligators',
  Lizards = 'Lizards',
}

type Animals = Mammals | Reptiles;
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is, that you cannot select any value from it. 
Error: `Animals` then. `Animals only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here`

Answer (score 3):

A very simple solution, [copied from here](https://medium.com/@resir014/hey-a-couple-of-words-re-enum-merging-7f67a2e92dea)

For two different set of enums:

```
enum WeatherType1 {
  CLOUDY,
  SUNNY,
  RAIN
}
```

```
enum WeatherType2 {
 STORM
}
```

You can then just use:
`type MyMergedEnum = WeatherType1 & WeatherType2;`
and then follow an approach of
`const foo:MyMergedEnum = WeatherType1.RAIN // or WeatherType2.STORM`

please note this is not a new enum, just a type.

Comment: 1. `MyMergedEnum` will only be a type, not an enum (as the name suggests), but that's easily addressed with a rename. 2. This may not work as expected for distinct Numeric enums (unless one carefully manages initialization, e.g. `EnumA { aFirst, aSecond }` and `EnumB { bFirst = 2, bSecond, bThird }`. 

Without initializing `bFirst` to the number of members in `EnumA`, the resulting type would be equivalent to `0 | 1 | 2` (which is the same as `EnumB`). With initialization, the resulting type is equivalent to `0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4`.   3. The answer doesn't actually address the OP.

Comment: thanks Rax, I have updated the answer since what you say its true, the comment doesnt directly solve the question.

Answer (score 1):

To merge the following enums,

```
enum Mammals {
    Humans,
    Bats,
    Dolphins
}

enum Reptiles {
    Snakes,
    Alligators,
    Lizards
}
```

we can do by the following way,

```
/** Animals */
const Animals = {
   ...Mammals,
   ...Reptiles
}
export type Animals = (typeof Animals)[keyof typeof Animals]
```

From the above, you can access the Animals master enum like below,

```
Animals.Humans /** accessible now */
```

Answer (score 0):

Tagging on a (maybe better) way to do this:

```
export enum Fruit {
  COCONUT = "COCO",
  BANANA = "BANANA",
}

export enum Vegetable {
  BROCCOLI = "BROCCOLI",
}

export const Foods = {
  ...Fruit,
  ...Vegetable,
};

export type Food = keyof typeof Foods;
```

Make sure the strings you defined the enums with don't collide. `Food` is the type, `Foods` is the underlying map defining the enum (which normally js would make for you). What's cool about this way is:

`Foods[Food.BROCCOLI]` is the string "BROCCOLI", just like how `Fruit[Fruit.COCONUT]` is the string "COCO", and with these types the compiler knows that.

So combining `Foods` and `Food` you get the standard enum behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
enum Mammals {
  Humans,
  Bats,
  Dolphins
}

enum Reptiles {
  Snakes,
  Alligators,
  Lizards
}

enum Animals {
  Humans = Mammals.Humans,
  Bats = Mammals.Bats,
  Dolphins = Mammals.Dolphins,
  Snakes = Reptiles.Snakes,
  Alligators = Reptiles.Alligators,
  Lizards = Reptiles.Lizards
}

export default Animals
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this enumerations example ------

**Enums or enumerations are a new data type supported in TypeScript**

```
enum PrintMedia {
    Newspaper = 1,
    Newsletter,
    Magazine,
    Book
}

function getMedia(mediaName: string): PrintMedia {
    if (mediaName === 'Forbes' || mediaName === 'Outlook') {
        return PrintMedia.Magazine;
    }
 }

let mediaType: PrintMedia = getMedia('Forbes');
```