# Get the value of an enum by key without knowing the specific enum type

Tags: typescript, enums

I have a type that consists of 3 enums.

```
enum TextItem {
  BOOK = "inventory.book",
  PAGE = "inventory.page"
}

enum FoodItem {
  BURGER = "food.burger",
  LETTUCE = "food.lettuce",
}

enum DrinkItem {
  WATER = "drinks.water",
  COLA = "drinks.cola",
}

type Item = TextItem | FoodItem | DrinkItem;

const getEnumValue(item: Item) {
  // What to do here?
}
```

An enum of type `Item` is passed in the `getEnumValue` function. Which item it is, I won't know. But it's certain it's of type `Item` (e.g. `DrinkItem.WATER`).

When passing the item in the function `getEnumValue`, how do I determine the associated string value?

I was thinking instead of Items I'd say `keyof Item`. But then Typescript starts complaining about item being of type never.

Comment: Can you also post the item you are passing?

Comment: An enum of type Item is being passed in the getEnumValue function. I won't know which item exactly is being passed.

Comment: This might help: [*How to merge two enums in TypeScript*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48478361/how-to-merge-two-enums-in-typescript).

Answer (score 0):

You should combine all the enums to a single object:

```
const MENU: IMenu = {
  ... FoodItem,
  ... DrinkItem
};
```

And the typing for this object will be next

```
interface IMenu {
  [key: string]: Item;
}
```

And in the function, you will easily call value that you need:

```
Menu[item]
```