# How to know with of the type is being passed in from a union type parameter in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

e.g.

```
export const getLabel = (
    type: PostType | UserType | PostStatusType | UserStatusType | ReportStatusType,
    t: TFunction,
) => {
    switch (typeof type) {
        case typeof PostType:
            switch (type) {
                case PostType.Article:
                    return t("article");
                case PostType.Comment:
                    return t("comment");
            }
    }
}
```

`PostType | UserType | PostStatusType | UserStatusType | ReportStatusType` are all number Enums.

`typeof type` is returned as number instead of one of the type. How should I do a match on it?

Comment: That's because these enums are represented as numbers at runtime

Comment: You can't. At runtime they're all just numbers.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen What is a good approach to handle this case? Separating it into different functions?

Comment: It depends a lot on how you call these methods, what else you're using the enums for, and whether there's any overlap between the different enum values. I find myself using string literal types a lot: `type PostType = 'article' | 'comment';` and so on. That still will not allow you to switch on the type though.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51498560/3558960) could be another approach.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen There are overlaps.

Comment: Just use separate functions. Any reason to bundle them?

Comment: `PostType`, `UserType`, and so on... are interfaces or classes or some type ids?