# Typescript - How to properly merge two enums that contain overlaps?

Tags: typescript, enums

Given the following enums:

```js
enum MyFirstEnum {
  A = 'A',
  B = 'B',
  C = 'C'
}

enum MySecondEnum {
  C = 'C',
  D = 'D',
  E = 'E'
}
```

What is the proper way of merging them? Note that they contain overlap in the key `C = 'C'`, so just `MyFirstEnum | MySecondEnum` may cause some trouble, for example:

```js
type BothEnums = MyFirstEnum | MySecondEnum

const myRecord: Partial<Record<BothEnums, string>> = {}
const someKey = MyFirstEnum.C

myRecord[someKey] = 'some value' // ❌ Property '[MyFirstEnum.C]' does not exist on type 'Partial<Record<BothEnums, string>>'
```

If I understood correctly from this question [How to merge two enums in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48478361/how-to-merge-two-enums-in-typescript), Typescript does not handle different enums with duplicate keys and values well.

But if one really needs to merge enums with this overlap, how to do it with no (or less) further problems?

Answer (score 1):

Is that would work ?

```
type BothEnums = {[key in keyof typeof MyFirstEnum | keyof typeof MySecondEnum] : 
  key extends keyof typeof MyFirstEnum ? key extends keyof typeof MySecondEnum ? (typeof MySecondEnum[key]  | typeof MyFirstEnum[key]) :
    typeof MyFirstEnum[key] : key extends keyof typeof MySecondEnum ? typeof MySecondEnum[key] : never}
```

equivalent to :

```
type BothEnums = {
    A: MyFirstEnum.A;
    B: MyFirstEnum.B;
    C: MyFirstEnum.C | MySecondEnum.C;
    D: MySecondEnum.D;
    E: MySecondEnum.E;
}
```

Needed to be call with keyof :

```
const myRecord: Partial<Record<keyof BothEnums, string>> = {}
const someKey1 = MyFirstEnum.C
const someKey2 = MySecondEnum.C

myRecord[someKey1] = 'some value 1' 
myRecord[someKey2] = 'some value 2' 

console.log(JSON.stringify(myRecord)) // "{"C":"some value 2"}"
```

But I would personally prefer this option :

```
const MyFirstEnumDef = ['A','B','C'] as const satisfies readonly string[];
const MySecondEnumDef = ['C','D','E'] as const satisfies readonly string[];
type MyFirstEnum = typeof MyFirstEnumDef[number]
type MySecondEnum = typeof MySecondEnumDef[number]

type BothEnums = MyFirstEnum | MySecondEnum


const myRecord: Partial<Record<BothEnums, string>> = {}
const someKey1 = "C"
myRecord[someKey1] = 'some value 1' 

console.log(JSON.stringify(myRecord)) // "{"C":"some value 1"}"
```

Comment: The second option is surely cleaner, but has the downside of not being an actual enum, but a type. Besides, the `satisfies` keyword is only available on TS 4.9, which may be not the case for everyone, since it is a recent version

Comment: The first solution works having only the small detail of needing a `keyof` to be called, but only works in the case where key and value are the same. If `MyFirstEnum` has a property `C = 'valueC'`, `myRecord[MyFirstEnum.C]` won't work, because, quoting TS: "Property '[MyFirstEnum.C]' does not exist on type 'Partial<Record<"A" | "B" | "C" | "D" | "E", string>>'"

Comment: You can remove satisfies readonly string[], with no consequences.

Comment: quoting TS: "Property '[MyFirstEnum.C]' does not exist on type 'Partial<Record<"A" | "B" | "C" | "D" | "E", string>>'". Good catch !.
then i have the feeling, nothing can be done perfectly. (i have tried to do something little different from the link you provided. They well explain why this will not be perfect. it looks i am not better than community :)  !)